# Redirect to another html file

Tags: nginx

I have configuration file:

```
server {
   listen 80;

   root /path/to/file/;

   location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/;
   }

   location /docs/ {
      index /path/to/another/index/filename.html;
   }
}
```

But when i'm trying to call /docs/ in browser i see in error.log that server trying to find docs file in root /path/to/file/ instead of returning another html file from second location block.

How can i proxy request /docs/ to another docs.html that located on file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` just describes what file to serve per default. The keyword you need is `root`:

```
location /docs {
    root /path/to/another/index;
    index filename.html;
}
```

Now the web server will serve `/path/to/another/index/filename.html` when the route /docs/ is accessed.

Comment: Now it's closer, but in log i have:
"/path/to/another/index/docs/filename.html" is not found

Maybe you know how to remove /docs/ from the path to file?